# Here Map not reloading tiles after window orientation is changed and resize occurs?

Tags: here-api

We are having issues with screen rotation with Here maps. On a mobile device browser, if we rotate the device, the page is rotated and the map is also somewhat rotated, but it doesn't seem to properly load up the map tiles. The image below shows what happens after I rotate the phone from portrait to landscape mode:  [image: improperly loaded map]

It looks like the UI (map buttons) are getting positioned as expected, and the map container seems to take up the entire width, but the map tiles don't fill the container. (The red marker is just overlayed on top using CSS and isn't actually tied to the map. It is supposed to be in the center of the container.)

Any tips on why the tiles aren't loading up on resize / orientation change?

I tried adding:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', updateViewWindow);
```

and also at one point:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', updateViewWindow)
```

with this inside of it:

```
hereMap.getViewPort().resize();
```

But it doesn't seem to be helping. I can confirm that the event is firing and getViewPort() is getting called, but it does not fix the issue. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

We are using the HERE JS libraries:

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A callback indicating that a user has rotated enough to be recognized as the two-finger rotation gesture. This callback will only occur if MapGesture is set to exclusive mode from MapGesture.setRotateEnabled(boolean)

MapGesture setRotateEnabled(boolean enabled)
Sets whether two-finger rotate interactions are enabled for this MapGesture.
Parameters:
enabled - A boolean specifying whether rotate is enabled
Returns:
The modified MapGesture itself.

Please refer for detailed reference
developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapGesture.html

Happy Coding..!!

Comment: I'm confused... we aren't trying to rotate the map through gestures. Rather we are rotating the entire screen and just want the map to also change orientation with it to landscape? It seems to be doing so but isn't loading all the panels (see image above)

Comment: Please use the latest version for better landscape orientation

Comment: Refer this interface which detects screen rotation : developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/ar/ARController.OnPoseListener.html

Comment: Hi, is there something similar if we're using Javascript? We aren't developing through the Android SDK? (I updated the original post to make this more explicit now)